# D3js loop through variable length series for scatter plot

Tags: d3.js, scatter-plot

I have data that can have a variable numbers of series. And inside each of those series is a date and number that I want to plot as a scatter plot in D3js.

This is my (non working) code. It works when I do it straight, but not once I add the $.each loop. I'm pretty sure its some sort of problem with indexing or something like that.

```
 var color = d3.scale.category20();
 // Now actually add the data to the graph
 $.each(mpgData, function(k, v) {
     console.log(v);
     //console.log(k);
     svg.selectAll('circle')
                 .data(v)
                 .enter()
                 .append('circle')
                 .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
                     console.log(i);
                     //console.log(d);
                     return xScale(getDate(d[1]));
                 })
                 .attr('cy', function(dd, ii) {
                     //console.log(ii);
                     return yScale(dd[2]);

                 })
                 .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                     return color(k);
                 })
                 .attr("class", "mpgColorClass"+k)
                 .attr("r", 5)
                 .on("mouseover", function() {
                     d3.selectAll(".mpgColorClass"+k)
                         .attr("r", 8);
                 })
                 .on("mouseout", function() {
                     d3.selectAll(".mpgColorClass"+k)
                         .attr("r", 5);
                 });
 });
```

I only showed what I think is the relevant part.

So that code kind of works. But it only shows 6 things, which I think is because the 2nd 'series' has 6 items. So somehow its not looping over everything at the "attr('cx', function(d, i)) part.  I think I'm not understanding how to get that function to loop over each part of the series.

I'm new to D3js, so still struggling through the learning curve. But it works and I get a graph out with the correct data. Its just not ALL the data, only 6 points out of the entire (variable) dataset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your $.each() block you are overwriting the same set of circles in the SVG element. So instead of using selectAll('circle') you can do this:

```
 $.each(mpgData, function(k, v) {
     svg.selectAll('circle' + k)
                 .data(v)
                 .enter()
                 .append('circle')
                 .attr('class','circle' + k)
 });
```

truncated rest of details in your code... edit at will.

Comment: Perfect. that fixed it. Thanks for the help!